# "has long been" or "has been for a long time"

Tags: adverbials

As far as I know, **'(for) a long time'** is preffered to **'long'** in affirmative sentences unless ***'long'*** is matched up with *too, enough, as, so, before, after, and etc.*

I read the following sentence on the website, however, and got a little confused:

> Smoking has long been linked to lung cancer.

http://www.onestopenglish.com/community/your-english/word-grammar/your-english-word-grammar-long/550209.article

This sounds perfectly natural to me, but I just wonder is it better to say "Smoking has been linked to lung cancer (for) a long time" because it is an affirmative sentece?

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overanalyzing, but that's partly because the linked article is a little confusing at the end.  In your sample sentence (as the linked article explained), it's being used as an adverb.  The type of sentence really doesn't matter.

The article mentions negatives at the end.  It says:

> As a noun, long is also normally used in negatives and questions and
>   means ‘a long period of time’.

That only applies to its usage as a noun, and even then it's *usually* used in negatives - this isn't a rule so much as an observation on the part of the author.

The rephrasing of your sample sentence, "Smoking has been linked to lung cancer for a long time," is more casual, and a bit less emphatic to my ear.  I would not say it's better.  For a professional or educated audience, I'd stick with the original.  Otherwise, it's up to you!

Comment: Thank you, Chris. 'Long' somehow got on my nerves lately. Aside from the sentence mentioned above, would you say "I have long waited him" or "I have waited him for a long time"? Do you think both are good? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Luxembourg  "I have long waited [for] him [to arrive]" sounds like something out of a medieval novel. Idiomaticity is at least as important as grammaticality. In your original sentence, because it is less 'conversational', the register is acceptable. But it _is_ formal, bordering on poetic.

Comment: I would not say either.  As Edwin said, "I have long waited for him to arrive" is extremely formal.  I'd expect to read that in an epic fantasy when discussing the "chosen one" destined to become king. ;)  In normal conversation, you'd say "I have waited on him for a long time."  Don't forget your preposition; "wait" is an intransitive verb, so you have to wait "for" him, "on" him, or "with" him, or so on and so forth.

Comment: "I have long waited for him" is not formal, but archaic. "Has long been linked to" is better in the OP's example because if you read the sentence as a whole you might monentarily think "cancer for a long time" rather than "linked ... for a long time", and a good writer tries to save readers from such momentary hesitations. So here we prefer "long been" to "been ... for a long time"

Answer (score -1):

I have a long wait for him can be used because 'long ' here is used as an adjective but instead of  I have long waited, you can use ' I have waited long for him ' Here 'long ' worked as an adverb.' Long waited 'can be used as a word. Example: Long waited reply.

Comment: RC, your example should be "long-awaited reply."  Not quite the same thing.